# Advice for creating character based off of Valiant Comics' Shadowman

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, new-players, new-gm

I'm a relatively new DM and one of my new players is wanting to create a character based off of the Shadowman character from Valiant comics and came to me for help. More specifically, he wants it to be similar to the "Magpie" version that appeared in Ninjak #10-13. So far, I've boiled this down to a few criteria:

1) Connections to a shadow spirit and/or a lich, as well as a "dead" plane,

2) Servitude based off of collection of arcane artifacts and enforced by some sort of magical chain,

3) Ability to innately inspire fear, and

4) Use of a magical scythe

I've been looking over the subclasses and I think either Shadow Sorcerer, Undying or Seeker Warlock, or maybe Oathbreaker Paladin could work, but I can't really determine which would be most appropriate. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. I do think this is a pretty good question because it specifies the criteria that are important to representing that character. That said, I assume phrasing it as a general request for advice attracted some of the close votes. Hopefully others can weigh in on what needs to be fixed to reopen the question. You may also have more luck asking on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/33569), or in [chat] once you have enough reputation to participate there.